# Open remote folder in local VSCode like "code ."in WSL2

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to use `$ code .` in remote server ssh session just like I do in `WSL` when I want to open current working directory in remote host in local VSCode?

ADDENDUM:
In local WSL, I can issue `$ code .` and that would open the current directory in VSCode which is installed on Windows 10.

I am trying to get the same behavior in another remote Linux which I have connected to remotely through `ssh`. So when I am on that remote machine and issue `$ code .` it would open that directory in VSCode installed on local window.

Comment: I think you're mixing [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) and [Remote - SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh).

Comment: So, it is not possible? Or do I need to edit my question to make it more clear?

Comment: You cannot use the WSL extension when WSL is not involved, if that's your question. Can't you just use the other extension?

Comment: I have added more explanation of what I intend to do. Maybe that helps more to understand the question. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps what you mean is that you want to start the connection from the remote server rather than your local PC, unlike when using *Remote - SSH*. You could install Visual Studio Code in the remote machine and make it communicate with a local X server but that can only be slow and burdensome. Never mind, let's wait for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't imagine this would be simple to do but I certainly share your desire to want to be able to do it.

## Problem

Here's an explanation of why it doesn't work, and a hint at why it's probably quite a difficult thing to setup:

The way `code .` works from WSL (or PowerShell) is by launching VS Code in the given directory (passed as the first argument as the dot).

When you run `code` from WSL it uses `wslpath` to convert the path to the Windows accessible one, and the WSL magic executes `code.exe` (which is, after all, a Windows binary and not a Linux one) in Windows with the WSL path (`\\wsl$...`);

## Theory

In order for this to work you need to achieve three things:

- Work out which remote you're connected to, and be able to pass that information to vscode
- Execute `code.exe` on your local machine, but from your remote terminal

## Ideas

A couple of ideas you could play with if you wanted to try and implement it:

- A script on your remote could output a `vscode://` URL for you to click (or find a way to get your client to auto-load it).
- You might be able to use a forwarded port in your SSH session to contact something on your PC (perhaps custom made, or maybe with Windows RDP or a telnet/ssh server perhaps?)
- Perhaps mount a local directory as part of your SSH connection (I don't know all the edges of SSH but it does a lot of cool stuff! SCP might help?) and be able to execute/trigger things?

Just some musings! It's not something I need enough to put any effort into it, but I came across your question looking for something else and found it interesting. Hope that's helpful to anybody, any thoughts/feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sshfs to mount a remote file system locally. This will allow you to work on the remote server with your local copy of vscode. The steps for windows are as follows.

1. Set up windows to use sshfs. Install the latest version of [WinFsp](https://github.com/winfsp/winfsp/releases/tag/v2.0).
2. Install the latest version of [SSHFS-Win](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win).
3. [Map the network drive](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win/blob/master/cap.gif) to the linux server. To map to the root file node you can use the following:

   ```
   \\sshfs\username@machine_ip\..\..
   ```

The remote server will be accessible like a normal directory. In vscode you can add a folder to workspace and write code on the remote machine without having to SCP stuff over every time you make a change.